# How can I stop timer and terminate program when result and userEntry are the same number?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

1. This is the class to generate a random number

The problem i have is whenever the random number and the user entry are the same I want the timer to stop, display the you won message and terminate the program.

If I close the program when the userEntry and result are the same it works but even if the number appeared before it displays the message you lose

That's why I want the timer to stop when the result is the same as the userEntry

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pega4Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TalkingClock lottery= new TalkingClock(1000, true);
        lottery.ask();
        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println(now);
        lottery.start();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quit Inner class program!");
        if(lottery.getUserEntry()==lottery.getResult()){
            lottery.stop();
            System.out.println("You Won!!!!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("You Lost!");
        System.exit(0);

}

static class TalkingClock {
    private int interval;
    private boolean beep;
    private Timer timer;
    private int userEntry;
    private int counter = 1;
    private int result;

    public TalkingClock(int interval, boolean beep) {
        this.interval = interval;
        this.beep = beep;

    }

    public int getUserEntry() {
        return userEntry;
    }

    public void setUserEntry(int userEntry) {
        this.userEntry = userEntry;
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(int result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public void start() {
        ActionListener listener = new TimerPrinter();
        timer = new Timer(interval, listener);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void stop(){
        beep=false;
        timer.stop();
    }


    public void ask() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter desired number: ");
        userEntry = input.nextInt();
    }

    public int  getRandomNumber() {
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        result= randomNum.nextInt(5);
        return result;
    }

    public class TimerPrinter implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.out.println("Print Run #" + counter + ": " + getRandomNumber());
            //System.out.println(getResult()+","+ getUserEntry());
            if (beep) {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                counter++;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop using the outdated class `java.util.Date`. Move to `java.time` API

Comment: Don't mix event driven GUI code with linear Scanner based code. Get the user's input in the GUI, test the input for correctness in an event listener, likely an ActionListener, and if correct stop the timer

Comment: You need to stop the timer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

You're printing You lose and exiting outside the if statement:

```
if(lottery.getUserEntry()==lottery.getResult()){
         lottery.stop();
         System.out.println("You Won!!!!");
         System.exit(0);
     } 
else {

     System.out.println("You Lost!");
     System.exit(0);
}
```

you should add an else statement.

Comment: The program still doesn't stop when adding the else staement